# 60079-11 / 7 PCB layout design rules

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers, hazardous-areas

Is there a PCB guideline paper or book that discusses how to design PCB layout and components that meet IEC60079 (-0, -11, -7) and how to limits the use of encapsulation or conformal coating.

In my case, I have an off shelve certified Zener barrier module attached to 4-20mA sensor device (protected input). The unprotected signal/power from Zener Barrier is then attached to my DAQ PCB, it has current limiter build-in on 24V terminal which avoids overheating in event of shorting faults. My DAQ board has lot of 0402/0603 res/cap but avoided tant/elec cap. (An expert for initial review suggested this board with 0603/0402 and small IC along with tracking layout does not qualify in IEC60079-11, I'm unsure why or which clauses in that standard apply). The power consumption of the board is less than few watts and mostly 5V/3V3 with 24V to 4-20mA sensor.

The IEC60079-0  (clause 5.3) defines a component with surface area, do they also apply to PCB as a component with 11,000 mm2 surface area? or do they apply to discrete parts?

It says Max Pd = 1.3W for +40C ambient, do they apply only for discrete part or whole PCB as a component?

How thick conformal coating, how to decide on that?

The DAQ unit resides in Zone 2 (Group IIB, T4).

(Ref: [PCB design for intrinsically safe equipment to 60079-11 standard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/376129/pcb-design-for-intrinsically-safe-equipment-to-60079-11-standard/478466#478466))

Comment: Draw a picture of the setup because, that is why EEs use circuit diagrams.

Comment: Intrinsic safety, and particularly ATEX, is extremely complex and highly application dependent.  Different parts of your circuit may have different rules.  The 1.3W, for example, is based on surface area.  I know more about ATEX design than most engineers, but my current project still involves weekly consultations and daily emails with my UL rep.

Comment: The surface area of a discrete component or PCB as the component, which is which?